# conditional rendering of div using v-show

Tags: vue.js

I have edit & save button in every row of the table which is created dynamically using v-for. When edit in one row is clicked, all other edit and save button should be hidden, till the row being edited is saved.

Comment: Please show the relevant code you already have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple example of the structure which you described. You can do it like this:

```
 <template>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="item in someDataRows" :key="item.id">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>
        <button
          v-show="!nowSavingId || nowSavingId === item.id"
          @click="edit(item.id)">
          Edit
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button
          v-show="!nowSavingId || nowSavingId === item.id"
          @click="save(item.id)">
          Save
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      someDataRows: [
        { id: 1, name: 'First Item'},
        { id: 2, name: 'Second Item'},
        { id: 3, name: 'Third Item'},
        { id: 4, name: 'Fourth Item'}
      ],
      nowSavingId: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    edit (id) {
      this.nowSavingId = id;
    },
    save () {
      // some save logic here
      // after save just do:
      // this.nowSavingId = null
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleh! I missed the point of using conditional statement in v-show. This works exactly as per my requirement.